# select2 bootstrap sizing issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I am trying to use a multiple select2 select form in my html with bootstrap. But I'm having issue with sizing, the select2 box is not working with the grid, and it also gurbles the size of next item. The html

```
<div class="select2-container col-md-11">
    <select class="form-control s2" id="complaint" multiple="multiple" name=
    "complaint[]">
        <option value="bad_breath">
            Bad Breath
        </option>
        <option value="bleeding_gum">
            Bleeding Gum
        </option>
        <option value="swollen_gum">
            Swollen Gum
        </option>
        <option value="gum_pain">
            Gum Pain
        </option>
        <option value="loose_teeth">
            Loose Teeth
        </option>
        <option value="sensitive_teeth">
            Sensitive Teeth
        </option>
        <option value="darkened_teeth">
            Darkened Teeth
        </option>
        <option value="damaged_teeth">
            Damaged Teeth
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".s2").select2({
    closeOnSelect: false
});
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

Full code here http://www.codeply.com/go/Ly1UHW2HT2

Comment: Too late for this thread, but if someone is using select2 from https://select2.org/ then please check this link https://select2.org/appearance which has the method to set the width of the control.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First Add in your select box : `<select data-width="100%"></select>`
Add This JS and CSS in you header :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had JS and CSS added but didn't use the data-width property.

Answer (score 1):

to fix the layout (widths not correct) you need to wrap the contents in a `form-group`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="select">Label</label>
    <div class="select2-container col-md-11">
       <select id="select" class="form-control s2" multiple="multiple" name="name[]" data-width="100%">
            <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Re the JS, I think there is an issue with codeply as copying the html and js and referencing the scripts and links directly in codepen works. See [here](http://codepen.io/alexander-holman/pen/XdPqMV) for an example.

Comment: Not working. Check the full code in the link please.

Comment: @Shawon0418 I think the problem is with codeply. i copied and pasted almost into my codepen [here](http://codepen.io/alexander-holman/pen/XdPqMV) and its working

Comment: It wasn't working in my browser either. It's working now after adding data-width:100%. Thanks for the help.